# Application of existence and uniqueness theorem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am relating to the theorem: $${ y'=f(x,y)}, f(x_{0})=y_{0}$$
Then if $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $I$ , then there exists a solution, and if $f(x,y)_{y}$ is continuous over $I$ then the solution is unique.

Given two real numbers $x_{ 0 } $ and $y_{ 0 } .$

Prove that there exists an interval $I$ such that $x_{ 0 }$  is contained in the interval I and there exists a solution to the initial value problem in the interval I. $$y'=y^{2},\quad y(x_{0})=y_{0}$$

Also,prove that there is a solution to the differential equation

$y'=y^{2}$

for every $x \in  \mathbb R $ and another solution such that there exists points $x_{ 0 }  \in  \mathbb R$ such that the solution is not defined.

I do not understand how I am supposed to prove this using the existence and uniqueness theorem.

Comment: I suggest reading the proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem, which involves setting up a contraction mapping, using the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Can you please give me some guidance? I am not on your level yet.